# Ruby on Rails ActiveRecord conditional validation (and more..)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, iframe, upload

I have a **Product** model which validates multiple attributes (including a Paperclip image attachment) like so:

```
validates_presence_of :name
validates_format_of :name, :with => /^([a-zA-Z0-9\ \-]{3,128})$/i
...
has_attached_file :image

validates_attachment_presence :image
validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]
```

Everything is working fine. What I want now is to make an *(unobtrusive) hidden iframe in-place upload script* using javascript. My problem is that I cannot just upload the image without the rest of the data, because it will fail validation (no name present) and also I cannot send the rest of the form without the image (same thing, fails validation).

So basically what I need (and don't know how to achieve) is to conditionally apply the model validations according to what the action is currently in progress (uploading the image or editing other data).

I hope I was clear enough. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/41-conditional-validations) have a nice video screencast about conditional validations.

Comment: now, I wonder how I didn't find that, because I *did* say "conditional validation". I'd give it a look and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I hate having to wade through a video just to get a simple answer.  In fact, I think that a blog entry is superior to a simple tutorial video simply for the fact that it is searchable.  Here is a simple case in plain text for anyone else looking:

To validate the presence of password only for the create action, do this:

```
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
```

Comment: "I hate having to wade through a video" <- You can use the sister site asciicasts.com

Answer (score 0):

A comment for Peter D.

Thank you very much.  I'm unable to watch that screen cast presently (though I plan to) and was looking for a speedy, brief answer.

Incorporated your suggestion into a model I have and it's working perfectly.  (Though I suspect at some point I'm going to need validation on update when passwords are being changed.  I'll take it as "technical debt" now though, in order to move on.)

The bit I added:

```
validates :password, :presence => true, :confirmation => true, :on => :create
```